# How to create tag automatically in SourceTree

Tags: android, ios, git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

Is is possible to automatically create Tags in SourceTree when there is a version change in the coding to be committed?

For instance, for iOS development, if `CFBundleVersion` is changed to `12` or `CFBundleShortVersionString` is changed to `1.1.2`, create a tag `v1.1.2-b12`.

For Android, create a tag named `v[versionName]-b[versionCode]` every time `versionCode` or `versionName` changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a [post-commit-hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), like described in [this blogpost](https://coderwall.com/p/mk18zq/automatic-git-version-tagging-for-npm-modules). Your `.git/hooks/post-commit` would look similar to this one for an npm package.json file:

```
#! /bin/bash
version=`git diff HEAD^..HEAD -- "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/package.json | grep '^\+.*version' | sed -s 's/[^0-9\.]//g'`

if [ "$version" != "" ]; then
    git tag -a "v$version" -m "`git log -1 --format=%s`"
    echo "Created a new tag, v$version"
fi
```

Essentially, you grep the required version strings from your `plist.info` in the first line and create a new tag in the `if`-statement.

Comment: That seems more detailed/specific than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [client hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks), you could consider a [post-commit hook](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/local-hooks), which would look at the last commit git log -p -l, and if it detects changes in `CFBundleVersion` or `CFBundleShortVersionString`, create the tag.

[SourceTree won't influence that hook](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/97823/answers/3599494).